# .htaccess advanced rewrite rule for numbers(digits)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an URL:
example.com/fruits12345/mango

I want to redirect it to 
example.com/fruits/12345/mango

*any number of digits after fruits should be redirected with fruits/NUMBERS

Tried But failed as it creates too many redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^fruits(.*)/(.*) /fruits/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(fruits)(\d+)/(.*) /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

---

Problem with your rule is that you are matching `.*` after `fruits` which matches anything so a redirected URL `/fruits/12345/mango` also matches this pattern and gets redirected again and again causing redirect loop.

Comment: Hello Brother! How Can I redirect this pattern example.com/fruits/7285/good-slug","id":"33b4","favicon_link":"https:/i.pinimg.com/fa/9.png       to this: example.com/fruits/7285/good-slug

Comment: it truncated the Pinterest arrays well, but it creates too many redirects.

Comment: I guess then it would be better to post a new question. Comments are not for adding new problems.

Comment: I recently asked, please see my latest Que